# how start elasticsearch with debug / verbose

Tags: mysql, jdbc, elasticsearch

i have a really hard time setting up JDBC river mysql connector with my elasticsearch installation

first i follow all the https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc howto

diffrence is where i install the elasticsearch from RPM repository via yum install elasticsearch, somehow it installed my elasticsearch in /usr/share/elasticsearch but the config are in /etc/elasticsearch

the problem lies when i installed the jdbc plugin, after installed already checked via `plugin -l` and yes there is a jdbc driver, but when i run bin/elasticsearch

it shows nothing helpfull just like

[image]

is it working? how could i show [DEBUG] and [INFO] ?

Comment: Can you please update with your elasticsearch version and the plugin you are using

Comment: @eliasah how buy yum update elasticsearch? its already the latest

Comment: I mean update your question with what version of elasticsearch are you using and what version of the plugin

Answer (score 12):

Outdated question, but probably, can be helpful for someone else.

`./elasticsearch -Des.logger.level=DEBUG`

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In the more recent version of ES, i.e. 7.x the option is

> -v for verbose

```
bin/elasticsearch -v
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a `log4j2.properties` file, typically in the config directory (along with `elasticsearch.yml`). There, you have full control over logging. You can set everything to DEBUG via:

```
rootLogger.level = debug
```

Though if I want more verbose logging for a specific chunk of code, I usually use the [Cluster Update Settings API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-update-settings.html). Something like:

```
curl -XPUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{
  "transient": {
    "logger.org.xbib.elasticsearch.jdbc.strategy": "trace"
  }
}'
```

Though the JDBC importer hasn't been updated for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/logging.html

Other ways to change log levels include:

**elasticsearch.yml:**

```
logger.level: DEBUG
```

After update the `elasticsearch.yml` you need to restart the node. Restarting one node will be enough to see the DEBUG logs on that specific node.

Default logs path:

```
tail -f /var/log/elasticsearch/*.log
```